# Find all occurrences from a string - Presto

Tags: presto, trino

I have the following as rows in HIVE (HDFS) and using Presto as the Query Engine.

```
1,@markbutcher72 @charlottegloyn Not what Belinda Carlisle thought. And yes, she was singing about Edgbaston.
2,@tomkingham @markbutcher72 @charlottegloyn It's true the garden of Eden is currently very green...
3,@MrRhysBenjamin @gasuperspark1 @markbutcher72 Actually it's Springfield Park, the (occasional) home of the might
```

The requirement is to do get the following through Presto Query. How can we get this please

```
1,markbutcher72
1,charlottegloyn
2,tomkingham
2,markbutcher72
2,charlottegloyn
3,MrRhysBenjamin
3,gasuperspark1 
3,markbutcher72
```

Comment: Not clear. Is it a Hive table with a single column? 2 columns? more?...

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - thanks for your response. 

The hive table has 2 columns. ID and TEXT. Ideally i would like to do a string token iteratively, when @ is present till SPACE. 

I was looking at strpos(text,'@'). But this gives only the first occurrence of '@' and not iteratively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  t.id
       ,u.token

from    mytable as t
        cross join unnest (regexp_extract_all(text,'(?<=@)\S+')) as u(token) 
;
```

---

```
+----+----------------+
| id |     token      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | markbutcher72  |
|  1 | charlottegloyn |
|  2 | tomkingham     |
|  2 | markbutcher72  |
|  2 | charlottegloyn |
|  3 | MrRhysBenjamin |
|  3 | gasuperspark1  |
|  3 | markbutcher72  |
+----+----------------+
```

Comment: Brilliant.. Thanks a ton for this.